# UNIX: find a file in directories above $PWD

Tags: bash, unix, shell, find, posix

I want to find a file with a certain name, but search in direcotories *above* the current one, instead of below.

I'd like something similar to: (except functional)

```
$ cd /some/long/path/to/my/dir/

$ find -maxdepth -1 -name 'foo'
/some/long/path/to/foo
/some/foo
```

Shell scripts or one-liners preferred.

---

In response to the several questions, the difference between the above example and the real find is that the search is proceeding *upward* from the current directory (and -maxdepth doesn't take a negative argument).

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to start at the parent of the current directory? Start at root and exclude the current directory? It's not clear what you want.

Comment: Do you mean exclude only the current directory?

Answer (score 7):

Interesting question, so I try to give a interesting answer :)

```
find `( CP=${PWD%/*}; while [ -n "$CP" ] ; do echo $CP; CP=${CP%/*}; done; echo / ) ` -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'foo'
```

A bit of elaborate,  the 'while' loop will try in generate list of path which is parent to current directory. The while loop won't generate /, so I add additional 'echo /' to cover that.

Finally, the enclosing "find" command is fairly basic usage.

Comment: It takes one year to the day, but finally, the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

This works, but it's not as simple as I hoped.

```
FILE=foo
DIR=$PWD
while [[ $DIR != '/' ]]; do
    if [[ -e $DIR/$FILE ]]; then
        echo $DIR/$FILE
    else
        DIR=`dirname $DIR`
    fi
done
```

Comment: +!, this is the essential method

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Parameter Expansion:](http://w3.pppl.gov/info/bash/Shell_Parameter_Expansion.html)

```
path="/some/long/path/to/my/dir"

while [ -n "$var" ]
do
  find $path -maxdepth 1 -name 'foo' 
  path="${var%/*}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean exclude the current dir:

```
find / -name 'foo' ! -iwholename "$PWD*"
```

If you mean: direct matches in any dir in the trail, this would work, but my bash-fu is not enough to easily get the list of dirs:

```
find  /some/ /some/long /some/long/path/ /some/long/path/to/ /some/long/path/to/my -maxdepth=1 -name='foo'
```

So all we need is a method to alter `/some/long/path/to/my/dir` to
`/some/ /some/long /some/long/path/ /some/long/path/to/ /some/long/path/to/my`

Comment: +1 This is clearly what is meant from the given `find` output, so why doesn't it have more votes?

Comment: If you plus-1 one an answer, make it [Zaricks one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826707/unix-find-a-file-in-directories-above-pwd/7614803#7614803), who worked it out.